# Save Mapbox-Vector-Tiles (PBF) on indexeddb and use them offline

Tags: postgis, leaflet, offline, pbf

I'm developing a PWA(Progressive web app) where I need to retrieve PBF files from a POSTGIS database, then save them on an offline layer, to work as a offline-first app, right now I'm using a PGRestApi

PGRestAPI:https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI

I'm trying to save this tiles using leaflet offline layer:
[Leaflet offline layer](https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline)
Is there a more efficient way to save those pbf vector tiles on indexeddb and then use them on a leaflet map?